# smartGWT and RichTextEditor: How to set the available Fonts?

Tags: gwt, fonts, smartgwt, rich-text-editor

I am using the RichTextEditor from smartGWT and it comes with 7 different fonts by default, but I would like to support ONLY 1 font type, and not 7, but the font I want to support does not come with the RichTextEditor. How can I set the supported font types from the RichTextEditor?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems that they don't expose much of that functionality in the RichTextEditor API, however I believe it could be achieved by doing the following:

```
RichTextEditor rte = new RichTextEditor();
// remove the font controls
rte.setControlGroups("formatControls", "styleControls", "colorControls");
// set the base font for the editor, could also be done with a <span> tag
rte.setValue("<font face="Bookman Old Style, Book Antiqua, Garamond"></font>");
```

Comment: I'm sure the API has changed. Answer is almost 5 years old. Unfortunately I haven't worked with GWT or smartGWT in a long time so I wouldn't know how to update.